# Having trouble getting font awesome icons to show up on nuxt app

Tags: nuxt.js

Im trying to get some font awesome icons to appear on a nuxt project(super unfamiliar with this framework) and I cant get the to show up.

this is my config file

```
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
    ['@nuxtjs/google-fonts', 
    {
    families: {
      'Press+Start+2P': {
        
      },
      'Space+Mono':true
      }
    }
  ],
'@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
'@nuxtjs/fontawesome',
],
fontawesome:{
  component:'fa',
  icons:{
    solid:true,
    brands:['faLinkedin','faGithubSquare'],
  }
},
```

this is where im trying to call in the icon

```
<template>
     <div>
     <i>
       <fa :icon="['fab','Linkedin']"/>
     </i>
       </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        
    }
    </script>
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.font-2p {
  font-family: "Press Start 2P", cursive;
}
.font-space-mono {
  font-family: "Space Mono", monospace;
}
</style>
```

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like? Does it have CSS styles associated with it?

Comment: the resulting html is just a blank white page and I edited to include the associated Css.

Comment: If there is no HTML at all, that indicates a much bigger problem than some icons not showing up, no?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.